# SQL where in sql subquery with order by

Tags: sql, sql-server

This is my query

```
SELECT * FROM Place WHERE Place.Id IN (
    SELECT TOP 10 PlaceId from #ResultPlaceList order by CPlaceId desc)
```

my result is ordered by Place.ID, but i want to have a result with ordered CPlaceId.

Comment: Does your Place table have CPlaceId column?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to do a `JOIN` to accomplish this. It will look something like this:

```
SELECT TOP 10 Place.* 
FROM Place
JOIN #ResultPlaceList ON #ResultPlaceList.PlaceId = Place.Id
ORDER BY CPlaceId DESC
```

Answer (score 2):

You could use a join to use the cPlaceId column for ordering:

```
select p.*
from Place p
join (
    select top 10 PlaceId,
        CPlaceId
    from #ResultPlaceList
    order by CPlaceId desc
    ) r on p.Id = r.PlaceId
order by r.CPlaceId;
```

Answer (score 1):

Something like this....

```
SELECT * FROM PLACE WHERE PLACE.ID IN (
    SELECT PLACEID
    FROM (
        SELECT PLACEID
            , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY CPLACEID DESC) RNUM
        FROM #RESULTPLACELIST
    ) TMP
    WHERE RNUM <= 10
)
```

Comment: Sorry. are you getting any error or not getting the expected output?

Comment: it's not what i expected for, anyway thanks for your attention

Answer (score 1):

'SELECT  C.ID
FROM CustomerDetails C
LEFT JOIN UserInfo U ON C.ID = U.ID
Order by U.ID'

Can you modify your query like this